# C++: Is it alright to keep creating new variables?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I have a general question. In order to solve any question in the exercises of the book I am learning from, while I am able to successfully solve the questions, I usually end up creating a lot of new variables within functions in addition to the ones that I have already initialised. For some reason, this worries me because I feel that I am writing inefficient code that might hog resources if I follow this practice for more complex programmes. Am I wrong in thinking this way? Are there any best practices regarding initialising and declaring new variables?

EDIT: I forgot to add, before resolving any question, I tend to convert the solution into plain English and then attempt to draw the program structure.

Comment: It's fine. You'd need to create thousands of them to cause any kind of resource problems.

Comment: @JonathanWakely But maybe it will make it harder for him to manage/keep track of all those variables

Comment: Jonathan's comment aside, you should strive to keep each function as simple as possible. It should do just one thing, preferably.

Comment: Yes, it might not be _good_ code, but unless he's compiling for a small embedded system, with a compiler that is bad at optimising, it's not going to cause resource problems.

Comment: Can you show us an example of some of that code? Also, if the code works as expected, this question may do better on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I would think it is hard to create too much redundancy here as I would assume your *extra* variables are essentially storing *intermediate* steps? I would think the compiler would create them if you didn't or it would remove the redundant ones if you did. But without an example from you showing exactly what you mean it is hard to tell.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Now does that mean creating yet another miniscule function, or inlining it? That is the Question.

Comment: Yes, miniscule functions are a good :) - makes maintenance much easier. Whether or not they should be in-lined is a performance enhancement decision best left for the compiler to decide, if supported.

Answer (score 3):

Normally compilers do liveness analysis of variables during the compilation of your code. Variables are considered live only starting from their assignment till their last use - optimizing compilers are capable of reducing the amount of local storage on the stack that is required by sequentially used variables (sometimes they even can eliminate their use entirely or keep them in registers only for a short period of time).

Comment: Be aware though that calling the dtor at scope-exit might constitute a use.